# PHP: Make convert.base64-encode stream filter return the entire result

Tags: php, io, base64

It seems like, when using PHP's base64 stream filter, it will chop off a few characters at the end of the stream. For example, this code:

```php
<?php

$string = "This is a test of all the things";
$stream = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');
fwrite($stream, $string);
fseek($stream, 0);
stream_filter_append($stream, 'convert.base64-encode');
fpassthru($stream);
```

The code prints the following: `VGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3Qgb2YgYWxsIHRoZSB0aGlu`, which decodes as `"This is a test of all the thin"`, chopping of the last two characters.

Is there a bug in PHP, or is there something I can do to address this problem? I have tested multiple PHP versions with the same results, but I don't see it documented anywhere. Either way, how to I go about ensuring I get the correct output: `VGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3Qgb2YgYWxsIHRoZSB0aGluZ3M=`

Comment: When I test this [online](https://3v4l.org/ElPHW), it works in 7.4.14 and greater. I'm not seeing anything in the 7.4.14 changelogs related to this, however. I do see in the 7.0 release there's mention of padding being truncated, and it references [this bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68532) which makes it sound like it might be a system library or package bug instead of a PHP-specific bug.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I guess I'll have to find a work-around for the time being then.